# Reading strings from text file as variable in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I am pretty new to programming, and have been searching for the answer to this, but I think I have been asking the wrong question in my searches.

Basically, I am trying to interpret strings from a .csv file as variables to use as arguments.

Anyway, I have the following code:

```
a = libtcod.Color(0, 176, 240)
b = libtcod.Color(100, 155, 200)
c = libtcod.Color(80, 055, 100)

def create_room(x, y, color):
    pass


y = 1

with open('Map.txt') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        for row in readCSV:
            x = 1
            for column in row:
                create_room(x, y, color)
                x += 1
            y += 1
```

Which runs through a .csv file and gives the column string for every x and y value in the file.

So, if the .csv file reads 'a,b,c', I want to call create_room(1, 1, a), create_room(2, 1, b), and create_room(3, 1, c).

Instead I think I am calling create_room(1, 1, 'a'), create_room(2, 1, 'b'), and create_room(3, 1, 'c'), which doesn't give me what I want.

This seems like this should be pretty easy to solve, but I either haven't found the answer or possibly found an answer but didn't realize it, heh (again, I am quite new to python and programming in general).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of three variables named `a`, `b`, and `c`, you should create a dictionary. That way you can look up the strings `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` to get their respective value:

```
#Initialize a dictionary with the appropriate values
color_lookup = {
    'a': libtcod.Color(0, 176, 240), 
    'b': libtcod.Color(100, 155, 200), 
    'c': libtcod.Color(80, 055, 100)
}

#Then call create_room like this
create_room(x, y, color_lookup[color])
```